# Prevent state leaking Scala class

Tags: scala

If I had to design this I would haven't used mutable state probably but dealing with following code from another project.

```
class MyEntity{
  var addressKeyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[Address,Int]().asScala 
  ....
}
```

In above snippet MyEntity class is leaking its state. Elsewhere it's used directly as myEntity.addressKeyMap. In order to contain the state in MyEntity class I can make 'addressKeyMap' as private and have an accessor method which copies 'addressKeyMap' into a new immutable Map. Is this how you'll approach to preserve state?

Comment: I know this isn't your code, but mixing `var` and a mutable map is senseless. It should either be `val` with a mutable map or `var` with an immutable map. I recommend the second, no copying is needed and thread-safety is guaranteed.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Why using var with an immutable map has no copying? If we want to change the map, we have to create a new immutable map and assign it to the var. Do you mean scala can optimize the creation and avoid copying?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner : I should have mentioned that reassignment of var addressKeyMap is happening in one of the methods in MyEntity class. e.g. addressKeyMap+= (add -> k). so using immutable collection will work as far as collection's own threadsafety is concerned. But reassignment of var is not an atomic operation hence usage of ConcurrentHashMap was required IMO. do you agree?

Comment: @cloud I was referring to how a defensive copy isn't required when sharing the immutable map. Internally, the immutable map is actually a hash trie and the updated map shares structure with the original map, so a full copy isn't necessary on update either.

Comment: @user2066049 True, var reassignment isn't atomic. If you are expecting a great deal of concurrent use inside of MyEntity then a val with the ConcurrentHashMap might be best. You could up-cast the map to collection.Map when giving code outside of MyEntity access. The methods to mutate the Map wouldn't be available, and so you might be able to get away with not doing a defensive copy.